# InDesign: Find a character at the end of each line

Tags: adobe-indesign, character

How can I find a character "-" at the end of the line in Adobe InDesign? I do not want to be at the end of the sentence/paragraph, but the line.

Comment: There's been a few similar questions on this and it generally boils down to looking at scripting, grep, or plugins.

Comment: Are you trying to look for word wrap or hyphenation? Or are you looking for stray hyphens at the end of a line?

Comment: There hyphens in the end of the line that need another hiphen at the beginning of the next line when the word itself already has a hyphen. I need to find these cases.

Comment: Sorry, don’t understand, can you paste an example?